# Dynamically require @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

How can I make 'Balance' (from code below) required or not required depending on the value of the DropdownList 'Credittype'?

Thanks,

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Credittype, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Credittype, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CreditType1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Credittype, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Balance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Balance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:120px" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Balance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is lacking pieces to work with. Are you using javascript? Where are the rest of your HTML? Are you using jQuery, React, Vue or any other frontend framework? (we need a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ValidationAttribute. I had fun with this, but it's also my first time creating a custom ValidationAttribute, so there may be better ways of accomplishing this.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field), AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true]
public class RequireWhenAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string _property;
    private IEnumerable<string> _targetValues;

    public RequireWhenAttribute(string property, string targetValues)
    {
        _property = property;
        _targetValues = targetValues.ToLower().Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_property);
        string propValue = prop.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance).ToString();
        bool isMatch = _targetValues.Contains(propValue.ToLower());

        if (!isMatch || (isMatch && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value?.ToString())))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ValidationResult($"The {validationContext.DisplayName} field is required when {_property} is set to {propValue}.");
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```cs
[RequireWhen("Credittype", "Low, Med")]
public decimal Balance { get; set; }
```

The first string is the property to check, and the second is a comma-delimited list of values it would be required for (you can of course just check for one value as well). You can check against multiple other properties by applying it multiple times.

```cs
[RequireWhen("Credittype", "Low, Med")]
[RequireWhen("Bankruptcy", "true"]
public decimal Balance { get; set; }
```

You could expand this to take in a single string containing an expression, like `Balance < 500` or `Title != CEO` with more string parsing, but this would work for the simple cases.

Edit: You can keep strong typing by using `nameof` as well.

```cs
[RequireWhen(nameof(Credittype), "Low, Med")]
```